# Javascript Templates calling with variables

Tags: javascript

So I have this code for example:

```
<script id='nice' type='text/template'>
<p>variable here</p>
</script>
```

So this is a learning question. I want to ask how to call this script in JAVASCRIPT NOT JQUERY with a variable which should be in the place of variable here.
Sorry if my question is so silly...

Comment: That is not a script which you can execute. Try to a) get it's text content b) insert your variable at the appropriate point (`replace`?) c) output the markup snippet where you need to. **Try that** - with native DOM methods or jQuery doesn't make much difference. Come back and ask a question about your code if you have problems with that.

Comment: @Bergi Sorry but I'm so new at javascript, I really need help with this. I don't even know how to do a, b and c. Though I do know that replace actually reloads the html, which I don't want.

Comment: For a) and c) learn the basics of DOM manipulation. It shouldn't be hard to find a tutorial on the web. For b) learn basic JavaScript [string processing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/prototype#Methods). Please use StackOverflow only for specific questions about code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want basic templating in javascript I suggest you use a library such as [underscore](http://underscorejs.org/#template) or Mustache.

In underscore you can do the following:

```
var template='<div><%=name%></div>'
_.template(template)({name:'foo'})
```

Which you can then insert into the DOM using your technique of choice.